# "Послепослезавтра" — есть ли такое слово?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Иногда, желая обозначить дату через два дня, мы говорим "послепослезавтра". А есть ли такое литературное слово или это чисто просторечное выражение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Послепослезавтра* - литературная норма.